# Taking a copy of my original List gets updated when it shouldn't

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a bit of code:

```
private List<Attributes> SplitDataBasedOnNextBranchToTraverse(Branches nextNonLeafBranchToSearch, List<Attributes> attributes) {
    List<Attributes> newAttributeListToReturn = attributes;

        for (Attributes attribute: newAttributeListToReturn){
            for (Branches branches : attribute._branches){
                branches.CheckRowExists(nextNonLeafBranchToSearch.ReturnAllRows());
            }
        }

    return newAttributeListToReturn;
}
```

Where I have a global list of objects which I pass into a method where I take a copy of the list. The copy list will get changed and should now not be the same as the global list I passed in. However when I debug my code and check the global list it matches the changes of the list within my method why? I don't want the global list to change it needs to stay the same! Any help to how I can stop this from happening by making both lists unique from one another will be much appreciated.

Comment: You are not passing a copy of the list, you are passing a reference and working on that

Comment: You havent created a new object.. newAttributeListToReturn is a new reference which is pointing to the same global List object......

Comment: Where in that code do you believe you're copying the list itself, and why do you believe so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assignment will just copy the *value* of `l1` (which is a reference) to `l2`. They will both refer to the same object.

Creating a shallow copy is pretty easy though:

```
List<Attributes> newAttributeListToReturn = new ArrayList<Attributes>(attributes);
```

(Just as one example.)

===================================== 
TL;DR

Java does manipulate objects by reference, and all object variables are references. However, Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them by value. Take the `badSwap()` method for example:

```
public void badSwap(int var1, int var2) { 
     int temp = var1; 
     var1 = var2; 
     var2 = temp; 
 }
```

When `badSwap()` returns, the variables passed as arguments will still hold their original values. The method will also fail if we change the arguments type from `int` to `Object`, since Java passes object references by value as well. Now, here is where it gets tricky:

```
public void tricky(Point arg1, Point arg2) { 
    arg1.x = 100; 
    arg1.y = 100; 
    Point temp = arg1; 
    arg1 = arg2; 
    arg2 = temp; } 
public static void main(String [] args) { 
    Point pnt1 = new Point(0,0); 
    Point pnt2 = new Point(0,0); 
    System.out.println("X: " + pnt1.x + " Y: " +pnt1.y); 
    System.out.println("X: " + pnt2.x + " Y: " +pnt2.y); 
    System.out.println(" "); tricky(pnt1,pnt2); 
    System.out.println("X: " + pnt1.x + " Y:" + pnt1.y); 
    System.out.println("X: " + pnt2.x + " Y: " +pnt2.y); }
```

If we execute this `main()` method, we see the following output:

```
X: 0 Y: 0 
X: 0 Y: 0 
X: 100 Y: 100 
X: 0 Y: 0
```

The method successfully alters the value of `pnt1`, even though it is passed by value; however, a swap of `pnt1` and `pnt2` fails! This is the major source of confusion. In the `main()` method, `pnt1` and `pnt2` are nothing more than object references. When you pass `pnt1` and `pnt2` to the `tricky()` method, Java passes the references by value just like any other parameter. This means the references passed to the method are actually copies of the original references. Figure 1 below shows two references pointing to the same object after Java passes an object to a method.
[image: Figure 1. After being passed to a method, an object will have at least two references]

Java copies and passes the reference by value, not the object. Thus, method manipulation will alter the objects, since the references point to the original objects. But since the references are copies, swaps will fail. As Figure 2 illustrates, the method references swap, but not the original references. Unfortunately, after a method call, you are left with only the unswapped original references. For a swap to succeed outside of the method call, we need to swap the original references, not the copies.

[image: Figure 2. Only the method references are swapped, not the original ones]

O'Reilly's Java in a Nutshell by David Flanagan (see Resources) puts it best: "Java manipulates objects 'by reference,' but it passes object references to methods 'by value.'" As a result, you cannot write a standard swap method to swap objects.

[Source](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077424/learn-java/does-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.html)